# Zimra - How I can handle key pressed event?

Tags: javascript, zimbra

I'm creating a Zimlet to archive a message by pressing a key. For example 'a'.
Can anyone give me a hint how can I listen for this key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at these blog entries:

- http://dennis.dieploegers.de/doku.php/my2cents/handling_keyboard_shortcuts_in_zimbra_zimlets
- http://blog.zimbra.com/blog/archives/2006/09/look-ma-no-mouse-keyboard-navigation-and-shortcuts-in-the-zimbra-collaboration-suite-and-the-kabuki-ajax-toolkit.html

Basically you need to add and register a keymap, than you can define key-handlers.